# How to check HTTP server keep-alive timeout?

Tags: http

I have two questions about http keep-alive.

1) If one sends a number of requests to a server, say

a) test.com/content

b) test.com/id

c) test.com/getcode

Each of the request is sent with keep alive header.  When the server is congested, I find that although I sent request (a) and got keep-alive, the next immediately sent request (b) response could be received after like 3s. (The response is very small in size). Is this sensible?

2) If the server only return "Connection: keep-alive" header. Is there any way to check the timeout value? If not, what is the default value?

Comment: Response time and keep-alive have nothing to do with each other. If the server is overloaded, it will be slow to answer either way. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection for information, like the default timeout of different servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Barmar says, keep alive and response time are not related.

The specifics of the keep alive are controlled by the browser. For instance, IE keeps the connection open for 60 seconds (configurable in the registry), Firefox for 115 seconds (configurable in FF settings).